# Chapter 1 to Chapter 5 or Chapter 1 until Chapter 5

Tags: prepositions

I want to tell the reader that:

- Chapter 2 explains the X theory.
- Chapter 3 explains the X theory.
- Chapter 4 explains the X theory.
- Chapter 5 explains the X theory.
- Chapter 6 explains the X theory.

How should I write a proper sentence to convey the message mentioned above?

> Chapter 2 until Chapter 6 explain the X theory.

or

> Chapter 2 to Chapter 6 explain the X theory.

or does anybody have better idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> Chapter**s** 2 ***through*** 6 explain the X theory.

Meaning: The (chapters *from* 2 *to* 6) explain the X theory.

Note: "Chapters 2 through 6" is a plural subject, like "they".

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with either of the two suggestions. More succinct is

> Chapters 2 to 6 explain the X theory.

There is no need to repeat the word **chapter**.